# What advantage does making api methods async gives if no new threads are being created?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asynchronous

I'm following this tutorial: https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/authentication-in-blazor-webassembly/
All the methods inside are async. What is the point? Async doesn't cause to create any new thread, so it's all single threaded asynchrounous. So what it helps with really? What would change in behaviour if it would be synchrounous?

Example:

```
public class AuthService : IAuthService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    public AuthService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
    public async Task<CurrentUser> CurrentUserInfo()
    {
        var result = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<CurrentUser>("api/auth/currentuserinfo");
        return result;
    }
    public async Task Login(LoginRequest loginRequest)
    {
        var result = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/auth/login", loginRequest);
        if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) throw new Exception(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
    public async Task Logout()
    {
        var result = await _httpClient.PostAsync("api/auth/logout", null);
        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
    public async Task Register(RegisterRequest registerRequest)
    {
        var result = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/auth/register", registerRequest);
        if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) throw new Exception(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at what [asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) is. "Asynchronous" and "concurrent/parallelism" is not the same thing.

Comment: @Xerillio I know, that's why I'm asking. If there would be concurrency then I get it why it's faster.

Comment: As @Mike notes in his answer, there's plenty of tutorials etc. on the subject - even on SO. Have you looked at some of it? What parts are you having trouble grasping? In a nutshell, using `await` frees the current thread to do some other work while waiting for the asynchronous work to finish.

Comment: @Xerillio Ok, but how does it decide what to do then, which part of code to execute?

Answer (score 3):

> What is the point? Async doesn't cause to create any new thread, so it's all single threaded asynchrounous. So what it helps with really? What would change in behaviour if it would be synchrounous?

The point of using `async`/`await` in client apps is to keep the UI thread free. The UI thread must be free in order to remain responsive to user interactions.

This is so important for a good user experience that many client-side technologies no longer allow blocking calls at all, and the handful of APIs that do permit blocking calls have been deprecated and only exist for legacy support (e.g., `XMLHttpRequest.open` if the code passes `false` for the `async` parameter).

I'd be surprised if Blazor allowed any blocking calls at all, since it is a newer technology. But if you did write blocking calls, then the browser window would be frozen during the call. Freezing windows for an excessive amount of time (e.g., for a network call when you can't predict how long it will take) will cause the browser/OS to step in with a "tab frozen" / "application unresponsive" message and offer the user an option to kill your app.

Answer (score 0):

Any function that uses `await` must, itself, be `async`.

These functions are making http calls which are, themselves, asynchronous.  Since those calls are initiated, but processing of the logic is suspended until the http call returns by their use of the `await`.

These functions will return pending promises, (a “promise” to get back to you with the answer), so you will either `await` them or set up the code to execute when the promise completes.

If you need more details, I’d suggest looking up any of the multitude of tutorials, that will cover the history of callbacks -> promises -> async/await, and to understand how JavaScript single-threading work by reading up on the JS event loop.